# Spring security Ldap authentication Exception : Not an instance of DirContext

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I'm trying to connect to a Ldap server (host by the company, don't have much info about it), using Spring Security, I have this bean:

> ```
> @Override
> public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
>     DefaultDirObjectFactory factory = new DefaultDirObjectFactory();
>     LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
>     ldapContextSource.setAnonymousReadOnly(true);
>     ldapContextSource.setUrl("ldap://ldap.company.domain.com:xxxx/dc=company,dc=com");
>     ldapContextSource.setDirObjectFactory(factory.getClass());
>     auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter("uid={0}").contextSource(ldapContextSource);
> }
> ```

But I got this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.NotContextException: Not an
> instance of DirContext; nested exception is
> javax.naming.NotContextException: Not an instance of DirContext
> at backend-1.0.0-RC1.war//org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:209)
> at backend-1.0.0-RC1.war//org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:824)
> at backend-1.0.0-RC1.war//org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadOnly(LdapTemplate.java:807)
> at backend-1.0.0-RC1.war//org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntry(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:260)
> at backend-1.0.0-RC1.war//org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.searchForUser(FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.java:100)
> at backend-1.0.0-RC1.war//org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.authenticate(BindAuthenticator.java:86)
> at backend-1.0.0-RC1.war//org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:174)
> ... 101 more Caused by: javax.naming.NotContextException: Not an instance of DirContext
> at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getURLOrDefaultInitDirCtx(InitialDirContext.java:154)
> at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:326)
> at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:326)
> at backend-1.0.0-RC1.war//org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:271)
> at backend-1.0.0-RC1.war//org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.lambda$searchForSingleEntry$3(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:260)
> at backend-1.0.0-RC1.war//org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:821)
> ... 106 more

when doing:

> AuthenticationManager.authenticate(authenticateToken)

Because it is working on another projet, using jndi, I know that Ldap info are correct.

Edit:
I tried to add:

> ```
>     Map<String, Object> baseEnvironmentProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>     baseEnvironmentProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
> ```

But still get the same error.

Do you have any idea why I got this error?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution using a LdapAuthenticationProvider:

```
 @Bean
 public AuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception {
     DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(List.of("ldap://ldap.company.domain.com:xxx"),"dc=company,dc=com");
     contextSource.setAnonymousReadOnly(true);
     contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
     LdapUserSearch ldapUserSearch = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("", "uid={0}", contextSource);
     BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
     bindAuthenticator.setUserSearch(ldapUserSearch);
     LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuthenticator);
     return ldapAuthenticationProvider;
 }
```